# Unexpected value change in 2D array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to modify one value in a 2D array. However I'm finding some weird behavior based on how the array is constructed.

The only difference between matrix and matrix2 is how they're constructed. However when I change the [1][1] value, all of the [x][1] values in matrix2 are changed:

Matrix:

```
[ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

Matrix2 (unexpected):

```
[ [ 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0 ] ]
```

Code:

```
var row = [0,0,0];
var matrix = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]];
var matrix2 = [row, row, row];
console.log(matrix);
console.log(matrix2);
matrix[1][1] = 1;
matrix2[1][1] = 1;
console.log(matrix);
console.log(matrix2);
```

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: `matrix2` has three elements, each of which refers to the **same** array. Simple test: `matrix2[0] === matrix2[1]` results in `true`.

Answer (score 2):

```
[row, row, row]
```

You just made an array with three references to **the same** inner array.

Changes to the inner array can be seen through any reference to it.

You want to create three copies of the inner array.
You can create a shallow copy of an array by calling `.slice()`.